# Autoplay YouTube video when visitors comes from specific site?

Tags: jquery, video, iframe, youtube, autoplay

I want to advertise my website on trafficmonsoon.com . On my homepage I have YouTube video (autoplay off), and I want the autoplay to be ON only for visitors that access the site trough trafficmonsoon. Is that possible and how to make it happen?

I've found some jQuery code to add autoplay on the iframe on button click, but don't know what method to use in this situation.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.referrer`

```
if (document.referrer === 'http://someurl') {
  // set autoplay on
}
```

You can also use a regular expression method for the `if` condition:

```
var targetRef = /^https?:\/\/(www\.)?trafficmonsoon\.com/i;
if (targetRef.test(document.referrer)) {
  // Put your jQuery code to add autoplay here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It return something like: http://trafficmonsoon.com/member/optools_ppc.php?ocd=activate&id=436355

But this link is not fixed, it changes after the .com/member/

How to compare only the "http://trafficmonsoon.com/", not the full url?